# Flash version 9,0 or greater required in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash

I'm trying to watch videos on [techtalks.tv](http://techtalks.tv/talks/autoencoding-beyond-pixels-using-a-learned-similarity-metric/62603/). Those are talks where the presentation slides are shown along the videos. Unfortunately this only works on my Windows machines (using Internet Explorer). Is there any way to make it run unter Ubuntu 14.04.

I already have the standard flash package installed, but it doesn't work in neither chrome nor firefox

Comment: Chrome does NOT depend on Ubuntu and handles flash internally; you probably need to set a flag/

Comment: True, I first thought this problem was related to Ubuntu since it didn't occur on my Windows machine. But it appears this is rather a problem of chrome / firefox than Ubuntu. Sorry for that

Comment: Well, Firefox OTOH does need a [plugin for Flash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I already found a good description to fix the problem in chrome on [this website](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784):

```
The site asks to download Flash
To the left of the web address, click Lock Lock or Info Information.
To the right of "Flash," click the Arrows Arrows.
Choose Always allow on this site.
Reload the page.

On your computer, open Chrome.
In the address bar at the top, enter chrome://components and press Enter.
Look for "Adobe Flash Player."
Click Check for update.
If you see "Component not updated" or "Component updated," you're on the latest version.
Go back to the page with the Flash content. If it doesn't open automatically, at the top left, click Reload Reload.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check again that Adobe Flash Plugin is installed and/or reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer
```

You can check flash support on official site on [this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/).

On my 16.04 LTS system the site shows video and right-clicking on it shows *Adobe Flash Player* drop-down menu.
It works on Firefox, SeaMonkey and Opera.
But Chrome reports

```
Flash version 9,0 or greater is required
You have no flash plugin installed
Click here to download latest version
```

as you wrote.